# String type in Python but with warning of "Number stored as text" in Excel xlsx file

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I need to create an Excel xlsx file from a Pandas data frame.

The Pandas data frame contains a column of Object type in Python. Each cell of the column is string type. On the Excel file, the column has warnings of "Number stored as text".

Why is it? Is it possible to remove the warning? It is already string type.

Code below:

```
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename,engine='xlsxwriter')

 df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1')

    workbook = writer.book

    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
```

Comment: It sounds like Excel is trying to make a guess about what the spreadsheet data is "really supposed to" be, based on the contents of the string. If you stored a string , that's all you can really do about it. This seems to be an Excel question, not a programming question - it's not Python's fault, and probably not your program's fault, that Excel is trying to detect suspicious data that happens to be what you actually want this time.

Comment: Probably precisely because the column is of object dtype with Python str objects in it.